# Form based on Database

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to generate a form based on some entries in my database (for a kind of survey), so the number and type of field isn't "static".

My problem is that I can't use Validators, because they are based on "static" Entities (for the `$form->isValid()`), so I would have only HTML5 constraints and no server validation.

How could I do that? Do I need to use [dynamic form modification](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)? How could I use it to use Validators with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possiblities to validate a form:

- You declare constraints with configuration for your entity (or class) by XML, YAML or Annotations.
- Or, you declare constraints into the Form Builder for each field.

Here are two links to validate your form without entity or class:

- [Validating values and arrays](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validating-values-and-arrays) - using validators outside of Entities
- [Form option constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-option-constraints) - add constraints inside the Form Builder